# Getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')" solana wallet connect

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solana, solana-web3js

So far it's been working fine, but out of the blue,without changing anything, I get this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')` in the line of code "await window.solana.connect()", worked before, but after a refresh it stopped working, nothing changed.

```
(async () => {
            // Connect to cluster
            var connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(
                solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'),
                'confirmed',
            );
            localStorage.setItem('connectionWeb3', connection);
        })();
        $("#buttonContainer").click(function(){
            (async () => {
                try{
                    var ownsNFT = false;
                    const resp = await window.solana.connect();
                    wallet = resp;
                    localStorage.setItem('walletFinal',resp);
              } catch(err){
                //
                }
            })();
       });
```

i removed some stuff including my call to the api because it included my private key and it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Please share minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: done, i did upload somee code

Comment: Seems like `window.solana` is undefined. Can you check that with a `console.log` or in the browser?

Comment: the thing that baffles me is that it worked before, one day ago, I changed nothing in my code, and now it doens't, I even reuploaded the old code from a backup and it still didn;t work.

Comment: gonna check rn wait

Comment: yes it comes back as undefined, but it came back as defined like a day ago

Comment: So where do you set the `solana` field to the window global object? Can't say anything unless I understand where it is set. Can you update the code to reflect that please

Comment: the thing is I get solana from a CDN, "<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>"

Comment: fixed it, the issuea was apparently that the wesbite wasnt secured somehow, and now that its https, it works.

Comment: Great, you can add this as an answer to the question, and accept it 2 days later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue, apparently because the website it was hosted on was http it didn't work, I forced https in the SSL and now that its secured it works. Strange but apparently that's how it works.